# Gitlab CI when never

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I saw this code on one of the pipelines of my company.

```
rules:
- if: 'SOME-CONDITION'
  when: manual
- when: never
variables:
...
```

According to gitlab ci documentation, the `when:never` field should be used with a condition, to basically tell the pipeline to not add the job if that condition is satisfied. I don't understand its use by itself in the end of the rules. What does it add and how the pipeline will behave without it ?

Answer (score 3):

I think that at the end of the rules block the line `when: never` tells that the pipeline should not be run in any other cases.
Because by default it runs after each commit in any crated MR.

Answer (score 1):

The last `when: never` is not needed.

Even without that line, the job will run only if `SOME-CONDITION` is satisfied.